# How to exclude an element based on its child in xpath

Tags: xpath, href, contains

I have a web page with 10 `<h4>` elements. using this xpath: (`//h4`) I can select all of them. However, I want to exclude one of them: the one that has an  as a child:

```
<h4>
    <a href = "http:///www.google.com"> "google" </a>
</h4>
```

Other nine don't have an `href` as a child. And I would prefer to do it in a way that doesn't explicitly mention the link text or address. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer. This works for me:

```
//h4[not(.//a)]
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.